# JQuery store value from for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had a grid and I want to fetch all the value into an object. But it seem only return the last value and I had no idea how to fix this.

```js
function item_details(){
  var gridDataArray = $('#itemGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.data();
  for ( var i=0; i < gridDataArray.length; i++ ) {  
    var items = {
      ["itemID_" + i]: gridDataArray[i]['itemID'],
      ["itemQty_" + i]: gridDataArray[i]['itemQuantity'],
      ["itemPrice_" + i]: gridDataArray[i]['itemPrice']
    };
  };

  console.log(items);
  return items;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

we need to declare the array before for loop and push the objects into it to store all the objects .

```
function item_details(){
      var gridDataArray = $('#itemGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.data();
    var items =[];
      for ( var i=0; i < gridDataArray.length; i++ ) {  
         items.push( {
          ["itemID_" + i]: gridDataArray[i]['itemID'],
          ["itemQty_" + i]: gridDataArray[i]['itemQuantity'],
          ["itemPrice_" + i]: gridDataArray[i]['itemPrice']
        })
      }

      console.log(items);
      return items;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Whyle the question is already answered, can additionally suggest to make `item_details` function a bit shorter.

```js
function item_details(){
  return $('#itemGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.data().map((item, i) => new Object({
      ["itemID_" + i]: item['itemID'],
      ["itemQty_" + i]: item['itemQuantity'],
      ["itemPrice_" + i]: item['itemPrice']
    }));
}
```